# How to handle NSZombies in an asynchronous NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsurlconnection, nszombie

I'm currently asynchronously using `NSURLConnection` with several `UIViews` (every view handles `NSURLConnection` as delegate). The problem I have is when user switches views too fast and the delegate becomes `NSZombie` the app crashes - that is NSURLConnection doesn't have living delegate anymore. So, the first question is if there's a way to circumvent this?

The second question is simple - how do I handle NSZombie? Simple `if(myObject != nil)..` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [cancel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-canBeConvertedToEncoding_) the `NSURLConnection` before you dispose it's delegate. Simply keep a reference to the NSURLConnection in your `UIView` that acts as a delegate and call `[urlConnection cancel]`.

After you release a message you need to set your pointer to it to nil if you continue using that pointer. As an example:

```
id myObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

/* Some code */

[myObject release];
myObject = nil;

/* Some more code */

if (myObject != nil) {
   [myObject doSomething];
}
```

Notice however that it is valid to send a message to `nil` so you don't need to safe guard the message sending. It simply won't have any effect if `myObject == nil`.

Comment: Thanks, [cancel] inside of viewWillDisappear was the right solution.

Comment: Although canceling the connection is good practice for traffic reasons, NSURLConnection's start method retains the connection's delegate, so it should not be possible for the delegate to become a zombie in the first place unless either A. you're overreleasing the delegate somewhere or B. it is already a zombie before you call [connection start].